# Traversing through a tree-like json

Tags: python, json, tree

I am new to python and trying to traverse through a tree-like json and print it in key, value pairs.
I am being able to iterate through the first level of key-value pairs but i am stuck at "data" which is a list of dictionaries and I want to iterate through each element in key-value pairs

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
abc = {
    "train_data_size": 537,
    "validate_data_size": 77,
    "test_data_size": 154,
    "total_data_size": 768,
    "no_of_columns": 9,
    "data": [{
            "Pregnancies": 6,
            "Glucose": 148,
            "BloodPressure": 72,
            "SkinThickness": 35,
            "Insulin": 0,
            "BMI": 33.6,
            "DiabetesPedigreeFunction": 0.627,
            "Age": 50,
            "Age_Dummy": 50,
            "Outcome": 1
        },
        {
            "Pregnancies": 1,
            "Glucose": 85,
            "BloodPressure": 66,
            "SkinThickness": 29,
            "Insulin": 0,
            "BMI": 26.6,
            "DiabetesPedigreeFunction": 0.35100000000000003,
            "Age": 31,
            "Age_Dummy": 31,
            "Outcome": 0
        },
        {
            "Pregnancies": 8,
            "Glucose": 183,
            "BloodPressure": 64,
            "SkinThickness": 0,
            "Insulin": 0,
            "BMI": 23.3,
            "DiabetesPedigreeFunction": 0.672,
            "Age": 32,
            "Age_Dummy": 32,
            "Outcome": 1
        },
        {
            "Pregnancies": 1,
            "Glucose": 89,
            "BloodPressure": 66,
            "SkinThickness": 23,
            "Insulin": 94,
            "BMI": 28.1,
            "DiabetesPedigreeFunction": 0.16699999999999998,
            "Age": 21,
            "Age_Dummy": 21,
            "Outcome": 0
        },
        {
            "Pregnancies": 0,
            "Glucose": 137,
            "BloodPressure": 40,
            "SkinThickness": 35,
            "Insulin": 168,
            "BMI": 43.1,
            "DiabetesPedigreeFunction": 2.2880000000000003,
            "Age": 33,
            "Age_Dummy": 33,
            "Outcome": 1
        }
    ]
}

# for k in abc.items():
#     for i, v in enumerate(k):
#         print("Key: " + str(k))
#         print("Value: " + str(v), "key: " + str(i))
data = json.load(abc)
new_dict = {}
my_list = []
for (k, v) in data.items():
    print("Key: " + k)
    print("Value: " + str(v))
    my_list = [{'data':x} for x in range(1,10)]
    for ke, va in enumerate(my_list):
        print("key: " + str(ke))
        print("value: " + str(va))
    # for key, value in new_dict.items():
    #     new_dict[value] = key
    #     print("key: " + key)
    #     print("value " + str(value))
    #     if len(value)
        # for ke, va in enumerate(value):
        #     print("key: " + str(ke))
        #     print("value: " + str(va))
```

I want to  see this in "key":"value" at all levels. I am being able to iterate the first set as in the first level. I am not being able to iterate through the list of dictionaries in "data".

Comment: Can you post what you desired output structure looks like?

Comment: Key: train_data_size Value: 537
Key: validate_data_size Value: 77
Key: data Value: 
key : Pregnancies value: 6, key:Glucose value:148, key:BloodPressure value:72, key:SkinThickness value:35, key:Insulin value: 0, key:BMI value:33.6,  'Age': 50, key:Age_Dummy value: 50, key: Outcome value:1
key : Pregnancies value: 6, key:Glucose value:148, key:BloodPressure value:72, key:SkinThickness value:35, key:Insulin value: 0, key:BMI value:33.6, key:DiabetesPedigreeFunction value 0.627, 'Age': 50, key:Age_Dummy value: 50, key: Outcome value:1

Something like this, if this makes sense.